# GMRES and Preconditioning

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

I am using GMRES to approximate the solution of a system of equations $Ax=b$,
I am using a preconditioner $P$ to make GMRES converge faster.

My question is how do I know if the preconditioner I am using is "good", I
mean, I have read that the condition number is defined as $\kappa(A) = ||A^{-1}|| \cdot ||A||$, the closer to one the better, but that involves to compute $A^{-1}$.
Is there a practical (not costly) way to know if the preconditioner $P$ is "good".
For example, in the number of iterations taken by the preconditioned GMRES,
how many iterations should it take to say that it is good?. Let say that the non preconditioned GMRES takes 1000 iterations to converge, and that the preconditioned GMRES takes 100, could we just conclude that the preconditioner $P$ is "good" or how can I measure how "good" (or bad) is $P$. Please help!!!

Comment: You need to estimate the condition number of $PA$; see http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/6805/how-to-approximate-the-condition-number-of-a-large-matrix

Comment: Well, you can judge the preconditioner quality by the performance of the linear solver which is not only reflected by the numbers of iterations but more importantly by the *time* required to perform these iterations. Obviously, if an unpreconditioned method took 1000 iterations in 1 minute and the preconditioned one does 100 iterations each taking half a day, then probably the iteration counts would not be such a good measure of efficiency :-)